# Access Multiple Family Group Users on 2nd Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-account

Our family just got a second switch so that two people can play different games at the same time. We have a family group Nintendo account, but when we logged into our account on the new switch it only added one user - the one who is the “head” of the family group.
How can we add the other family members as users on the new switch?